# How do I filter a column derived from window function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table which is as below

```
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------+--------+
| OrderID |    OrderDate    |    ShipDate     |    CustomerName    |     City     | Sales | Profit |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------+--------+
|    1001 | 11/8/2016 0:00  | 11/11/2016 0:00 | Claire Gute        | Henderson    |   262 |     42 |
|    1002 | 11/8/2016 0:00  | 11/11/2016 0:00 | Darrin Van Huff    | Henderson    |   732 |    220 |
|    1003 | 6/12/2016 0:00  | 6/16/2016 0:00  | Claire Gute        | Henderson    |    15 |      7 |
|    1004 | 10/11/2015 0:00 | 10/18/2015 0:00 | Brosina Hoffman    | Henderson    |   958 |   -383 |
|    1005 | 10/11/2015 0:00 | 10/18/2015 0:00 | Claire Gute        | Henderson    |    22 |      3 |
|    1006 | 6/9/2014 0:00   | 6/14/2014 0:00  | Irene Maddox       | Fort Worth   |    49 |     14 |
|    1007 | 6/9/2014 0:00   | 6/14/2014 0:00  | Harold Pawlan      | Fort Worth   |     7 |      2 |
|    1008 | 6/9/2014 0:00   | 6/14/2014 0:00  | Pete Kriz          | Fort Worth   |   907 |     91 |
|    1009 | 6/9/2014 0:00   | 6/14/2014 0:00  | Irene Maddox       | Fort Worth   |    19 |      6 |
|    1010 | 6/9/2014 0:00   | 6/14/2014 0:00  | Zuschuss Donatelli | Fort Worth   |   115 |     34 |
|    1011 | 6/9/2014 0:00   | 6/14/2014 0:00  | Ken Black          | Philadelphia |  1706 |     85 |
|    1012 | 6/9/2014 0:00   | 6/14/2014 0:00  | Sandra Flanagan    | Philadelphia |   911 |     68 |
|    1013 | 4/15/2017 0:00  | 4/20/2017 0:00  | Ken Black          | Philadelphia |    16 |      5 |
|    1014 | 12/5/2016 0:00  | 12/10/2016 0:00 | Eric Hoffmann      | Philadelphia |   408 |    133 |
|    1015 | 11/22/2015 0:00 | 11/26/2015 0:00 | Tracy Blumstein    | Naperville   |    69 |   -124 |
|    1016 | 11/22/2015 0:00 | 11/26/2015 0:00 | Matt Abelman       | Melbourne    |     3 |     -4 |
|    1017 | 11/22/2015 0:00 | 11/26/2015 0:00 | Gene Hale          | Melbourne    |   666 |     13 |
|    1018 | 5/13/2014 0:00  | 5/15/2014 0:00  | Steve Nguyen       | Melbourne    |    56 |     10 |
|    1019 | 5/13/2014 0:00  | 5/15/2014 0:00  | Linda Cazamias     | Dover        |     9 |      2 |
|    1020 | 5/13/2014 0:00  | 5/15/2014 0:00  | Ruben Ausman       | Dover        |   113 |     35 |
+---------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------+-------+--------+
```

I write below query to get the `rank` within each `city` for a given order based on `Sales`

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipDate, CustomerName, City, Sales, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Sales DESC) as RankA 
FROM Table1
```

I get below result which is absolutely correct

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------+-------+
| OrderID |      OrderDate      |      ShipDate       |    CustomerName    |     City     | Sales | RankA |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------+-------+
|    1020 | 2014-05-13 00:00:00 | 2014-05-15 00:00:00 | Ruben Ausman       | Dover        |   113 |     1 |
|    1019 | 2014-05-13 00:00:00 | 2014-05-15 00:00:00 | Linda Cazamias     | Dover        |     9 |     2 |
|    1008 | 2014-06-09 00:00:00 | 2014-06-14 00:00:00 | Pete Kriz          | Fort Worth   |   907 |     1 |
|    1010 | 2014-06-09 00:00:00 | 2014-06-14 00:00:00 | Zuschuss Donatelli | Fort Worth   |   115 |     2 |
|    1006 | 2014-06-09 00:00:00 | 2014-06-14 00:00:00 | Irene Maddox       | Fort Worth   |    49 |     3 |
|    1009 | 2014-06-09 00:00:00 | 2014-06-14 00:00:00 | Irene Maddox       | Fort Worth   |    19 |     4 |
|    1007 | 2014-06-09 00:00:00 | 2014-06-14 00:00:00 | Harold Pawlan      | Fort Worth   |     7 |     5 |
|    1004 | 2015-10-11 00:00:00 | 2015-10-18 00:00:00 | Brosina Hoffman    | Henderson    |   958 |     1 |
|    1002 | 2016-11-08 00:00:00 | 2016-11-11 00:00:00 | Darrin Van Huff    | Henderson    |   732 |     2 |
|    1001 | 2016-11-08 00:00:00 | 2016-11-11 00:00:00 | Claire Gute        | Henderson    |   262 |     3 |
|    1005 | 2015-10-11 00:00:00 | 2015-10-18 00:00:00 | Claire Gute        | Henderson    |    22 |     4 |
|    1003 | 2016-06-12 00:00:00 | 2016-06-16 00:00:00 | Claire Gute        | Henderson    |    15 |     5 |
|    1017 | 2015-11-22 00:00:00 | 2015-11-26 00:00:00 | Gene Hale          | Melbourne    |   666 |     1 |
|    1018 | 2014-05-13 00:00:00 | 2014-05-15 00:00:00 | Steve Nguyen       | Melbourne    |    56 |     2 |
|    1016 | 2015-11-22 00:00:00 | 2015-11-26 00:00:00 | Matt Abelman       | Melbourne    |     3 |     3 |
|    1015 | 2015-11-22 00:00:00 | 2015-11-26 00:00:00 | Tracy Blumstein    | Naperville   |    69 |     1 |
|    1011 | 2014-06-09 00:00:00 | 2014-06-14 00:00:00 | Ken Black          | Philadelphia |  1706 |     1 |
|    1012 | 2014-06-09 00:00:00 | 2014-06-14 00:00:00 | Sandra Flanagan    | Philadelphia |   911 |     2 |
|    1014 | 2016-12-05 00:00:00 | 2016-12-10 00:00:00 | Eric Hoffmann      | Philadelphia |   408 |     3 |
|    1013 | 2017-04-15 00:00:00 | 2017-04-20 00:00:00 | Ken Black          | Philadelphia |    16 |     4 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------+-------+-------+
```

But now I have two requests

1. To keep only those rows where `RankA` is 1
2. To keep only those rows where `RankA` is less than 3 (that is 1 or 2)

I am not getting how do I filter `RankA` column

I am open for solution in `SQL-Server` and `mysql`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use subquery and then apply filter

```
select * from (
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipDate, CustomerName, City, Sales, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Sales DESC) as RankA 
FROM Table1
) t where t.RankA=1
```

you can write it  by using cte

```
with cte as
(
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipDate, CustomerName, City, Sales, 
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Sales DESC) as RankA 
FROM Table1
) select * from cte
  where cte.RankA<3
```

Comment: . . .  First point should cover in second point. So, first point is unnecessary.

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Done. Sorry for delay

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery or CTE:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipDate, CustomerName, City, Sales, 
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Sales DESC) as RankA 
      FROM Table1
     ) t
where RankA <= 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

As stated by @sql_learner, this my answer is wrong. Window functions like the one requested can only be used in the SELECT or ORDER BY expressions. Filtering with the HAVING clause is only possible for aggregate functions (like COUNT, SUM etc.), not for window functions.

Thanks for pointing it out.

**Original Post**

You can filter by aggregate results using a [HAVING](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause:

```
SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipDate, CustomerName, City, Sales, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Sales DESC) as RankA 
FROM Table1
HAVING RankA = 1

SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, ShipDate, CustomerName, City, Sales, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Sales DESC) as RankA 
FROM Table1
HAVING RankA < 3
```

Comment: Having doesn't seem to work in `mysql`. Is it only for `sql-server` ?. I tried it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e79cciNYBBtgaaGKcRauV4/0)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't pay enough attention, the answer is simply wrong. Will state as such.